# How to use <input> for IBAN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use an input so the user inputs a German IBAN like:

```
DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00
```

I don't need **DE** part but the numbers should have the spaces as above. I also want to limit the input to 20 numbers.

I'm using HTML,AngularJS(javascript)

**Any help please?**

PS: If it's easier I can input all 20 numbers and when i click outside the input, it formats.

```js
   // Function to format IBAN
    function formatIBAN() {
      //TODO
    };
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span>DE</span></span>
    <input type="number" ng-model="vm.NewReferenceAccount.newReferenceNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the IBAN" ng-keyup="formatIBAN();">
</div>
```

Comment: Try using input type "tel" instead of number e.g <input id='with_space' type='tel'>

Comment: So if you use AngularJS you can create new directive that requires ngModel and use $formatters (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$formatters) to format view value as you want to look like.

Comment: Oh, I probably misunderstood you. You want to change value to has no whitespaces, right? So you can use $parsers rather than $formatters, to change model value with view value left unchanged. 
Summarize, you will have "89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00" in your input and this value user will see and "89370400440532013000" in your code (you will see it when, for example, use console.log statement).

Comment: no... I want the user to input a string of numbers WITHOUT spaces and the inputs shows with spaces....

Comment: So my advice in first comment is correct.. Using $formatters will be enough to solve your problem..